# Angular - $http, $q load json

Tags: angularjs, http

Still trying to learn Angular.

I have a plunker here - https://plnkr.co/edit/oEXn5JDKeqoN82jz3PC1?p=preview

Trying to load external json file using $http and $q

I have a simpleController calling a getJson() function in a simpleService file to load the json.

Just trying to output the data on the home page to start with.

Locally I'm getting an error in the console saying

```
        TypeError: simpleService.getJson is not a function
```

The service

```js
(function() {

  angular.module('cxoAppJs').service('simpleService', simpleService);

  simpleService.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];

  function simpleService($http, $q) {

    function getJson() {

      var deferred = $q.defer();

      http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/gznzh').then(function() {

        deferred.resolve(data);

        return deferred.promise;

      })

    }

  }

})();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Tome Pejoski says, you dont need to wrap the $http.get function

but your error isnt a problem with the wrapping byself. You have to return your functions in a service to get access to it

```
(function(){
      angular.module('cxoAppJs').service('simpleService', simpleService);

      simpleService.$inject = ['$http', '$q'];
      function simpleService($http, $q){
        var service = {};
        service.getJson = function(){ return $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/gznzh');};
        return service;
      }
})();
```

After that you can call it in your Controller

```
angular.module('cxoAppJs').controller('ExampleCtrl', ExampleCtrl);
ExampleCtrl.$inject('$scope', 'simpleService');
function ExampleCtrl($scope, simpleService){
  $scope.exampleData = {};
  simpleService.getJson().then(function(request){
     $scope.exampleData = request.data
  })
}
```

Edit:

[Quick Example Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/jj9Keu8IzR9eKs8oY4cv?p=preview)

Comment: got your Plunkter to work too: 

https://plnkr.co/edit/TOiRJzxdlb8fXgY4Pedi?p=preview

Happy Coding!!

Comment: You have to include your separate JS files too, and I fixed some small issues with naming and typing

Comment: Thanks 42tg I can see how the plunker works but I was trying to do this with  $q and defer. I know $http returns a promise but Ive seen examples using $q and I was trying to understand how to do that. I'll try and update my plunker and question.

Comment: [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/jj9Keu8IzR9eKs8oY4cv?p=preview) is an example how to do it with $q directly, added two ways of creating promises, choose what you like more and welcome to the promise chaining :)

Comment: Just to add an important notice the return $q((resolve,reject)=>{}) shorthand function only works with angular >= 1.3.0

Comment: Thank you again for your help 42tg. I have another plunker here of the structure I'm trying t get working https://plnkr.co/edit/6ASJ38QtIjtBCm5hNzkZ?p=preview I'm trying to use a service that calls a HTTPService which then calls a commonHTTPService

Comment: This is drifting a little bit off the initial question right now. Maye ask a new Question next time. Your issue with your plunker is mostly spelling errors and again not returning the service object at creation. After I fixed them everything works fine. [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Sn8rRTbj9vIjTvfRE5vL?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for help 42tg

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to wrap the HTTP call in a promise. `$http` automatically creates a promise.

Your code should look like this:

```
$http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/gznzh').then(function(result){
  return result.data;       
}
```